# combine two xpath expretion with the same prefix

Tags: xpath, operator-keyword, prefix

I'm trying to find some way to merge the result of two xpath queries with the same prefix.

Say: /inventory/product/itemNumber | /inventory/product/itemName

I'm looking for something like /inventory/product/(itemNumber | itemName) (the order of the output is irreverent for me).

Basically, I'm trying to find a way not to write the long prefix twice.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to accomplish this is the following:

```
/inventory/product/*[self::itemNumber or self::itemName]
```